# How to get dark tone (shade) color from image like twitter in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bitmap, uiimage, uicolor

I want to get the similar effect twitter uses when looking for images in full screen mode. Is there any algorithm to get the darkest tone or shade from image?

Attaching desired effect:

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMEGX.jpg*

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPLjH.jpg*

*https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdAXP.jpg*

Currently using below code to get average color:

```
func averageColor() -> UIColor {
    var bitmap = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        // Get average color.
        let context = CIContext()
        let inputImage: CIImage = ciImage ?? CoreImage.CIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
        let extent = inputImage.extent
        let inputExtent = CIVector(x: extent.origin.x, y: extent.origin.y, z: extent.size.width, w: extent.size.height)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage", withInputParameters: [kCIInputImageKey: inputImage, kCIInputExtentKey: inputExtent])!
        let outputImage = filter.outputImage!
        let outputExtent = outputImage.extent
        assert(outputExtent.size.width == 1 && outputExtent.size.height == 1)

        // Render to bitmap.
        context.render(outputImage, toBitmap: &bitmap, rowBytes: 4, bounds: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), format: kCIFormatRGBA8, colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB())
    } else {
        // Create 1x1 context that interpolates pixels when drawing to it.
        let context = CGContext(data: &bitmap, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
        let inputImage = cgImage ?? CIContext().createCGImage(ciImage!, from: ciImage!.extent)

        // Render to bitmap.
        context.draw(inputImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
    }

    // Compute result.
    let result = UIColor(red: CGFloat(bitmap[0]) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(bitmap[1]) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(bitmap[2]) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(bitmap[3]) / 255.0)
    return result
}
```

Comment: What you have tries any example code  you tried?
Also your question is not clear no one will respond on  ambiguous question. please purify your need and ask again .you can also try adding an example image.

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I am using average color from image. I want Dark muted like color in android color palette. Added code in question which I am using currently.

Comment: @AnastasiaKovaleva, I want to set background color for imageview to use darker tone from image itself.

Comment: @KishanLal Please add screenshot of the effect you are trying to replicate, it will help others to answer your question, and future visitors will be able to understand what you're requesting even after Twitter changes their UI

Comment: @Marmoy, Attached desired effect in post.